# vscode.workspace.openTextDocument fails silently

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

With the same value for Uri, `openTextDocument` fails to have any discernible effect yet `executeCommand` successfully opens the document.

```
vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(uri);
vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.open", uri);
```

Are there any known problems with `vscode.workspace.openTextDocument`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might simply be a misunderstanding of what `openTextDocument()` *does*. It just creates a `vscode.TextDocument` instance, actually showing it in the UI is independent of that. That's why it's in the `vscode.workspace` namespace rather than `vscode.window`.

[`vscode.window.showTextDocument`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.showTextDocument) is used for actually showing a document:

> Show the given document in a text editor. A column can be provided
>   to control where the editor is being shown. Might change the active editor.

```ts
vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(...).then(
    document => vscode.window.showTextDocument(document));
```

Comment: I didn't even notice that it was a method on the workspace rather than the window. Too much convenience and editor magic (autocomplete).